# Передача данных между серверами

Tags: python, база-данных, алгоритм

Есть веб-интерфейс, через который управляется приложение. Есть сервер-обработчик, который висит на другом порту и обрабатывает запросы приложений клиентов. Эти 2 сервера никак не связаны между собой (1-ый висит на отдельном порту, другой - на другом)

Как сервер-обработчик должен передать данные от клиентов к веб-интерфейсу? Как связать эти два элемента?

P.S. Веб-интерфейс и сервер-обработчик написан, например, на `Python`. Также нужен real-time.

Comment: Сервер очередей.

Comment: что вы под словами "real-time" подразумеваете? Вы хотите, чтобы веб-сервер не возвращал бы ответ пока "сервер-обработчик" результат не вернёт? (то есть вы хотите синхронно запрос выполнялся). Или будет достаточно, чтобы веб-сервер в очередь выставлял задачу, которую "сервер-обработчик" уже позже мог бы выполнить? (асинхронное выполнение)

Comment: к серверу-обработчику будут приходиться запросы, нужно сразу перекидывать некоторые данные из этих запросов к веб-интерфейсу

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего использовать то хранилище, которое уже применяется в задаче. Если используется SQL какой-то, можно к нему обращаться с обоих серверов.

Можно redis, если используется он как БД.

Если надо передавать задания, то часто выбирают rabbit.

Comment: Да правильно, только базу не рекомендую использовать. Если на сервер один два клиента заходят то можно 

Comment: если использовать БД, разве будет реал-тайм? БД же нужно будет проверять через n секунд, на наличие новых записей, не?

Comment: Ну в redis, например, есть сообщения, многие SQL тоже могут что-то вызвать по срабатыванию условий. А посмотрев "внимательнее" на задачу, подумал, почему бы второму серверу просто не вызвать веб-интерфейс первого, раз уже есть веб-интерфейс.